# "In practise" or "In practice"

Tags: british-english

British English makes the distinction between 'practise' (verb) and 'practice' (noun).

Based on this, I would judge the following sentence as **incorrect**:

> In practise, computers often crash.

Nevertheless, I see it frequently. Could 'practise' possibly be a verb in this phrase?

Comment: Verbs don't take prepositions. That's why gerunds got invented.

Comment: General Reference. Also, the verb/noun spelling distinction [isn't just Br. Eng.](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+practice%2Cin+practise&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=5&smoothing=3)

Comment: The verb/noun spelling distinction [isn't present in Am. Eng.](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=practicing%2Cpractising%2Cthe+practice%2Cthe+practise&year_start=1700&year_end=2009&corpus=5&smoothing=3) because they're both spelled with a 'c' (more precisely, two 'c's).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I agree, the usage is incorrect.  It would be a noun in that sentence, synonymous (or almost so) with "in fact" or "in reality", and an antonym to "in theory".

Answer (score 8):

**You must definitely write: *a* practice, but *to* practise.**

Exactly when as you write : an advice, to advise; or: a device, to devise...

The reason is etymological, from French (and don't ignore that two thirds of the English vocabulary comes from over The Channel, it explains numerous oddities in English spelling and pronunciation - in fact regularities in French, or rather old French).

Take for instance:
a) advice: the old French was "un advis" (the "d" is now dropped); it was pronounced, and still is in Southern France: *avisse* (*avi* in the North).
b) advise: the verb was "adviser" (the "d" is now dropped, too); it is pronounced *avizer*

The French rules ensue themselves from Latin.

*in practise* is therefore incorrect; the confusion comes from the USA; the immigrants have not always been good grammarians, and they still have no reference like Oxford or l'Académie

Comment: The factual parts of this answer are well-done, and the comparison to _advise/devise_ is illuminating. However, I find the nonstandard punctuation and spacing distracting, and the provincial attitude toward Americans mildly offensive. +1/–1 = 0.

Comment: You wouldn't write "an advice" as advice is uncountable in English.
Some advice or a piece of advice.

Comment: @user195536: There is also a countable sense: "a formal notice of a financial transaction: *remittance advices.*" (Oxford Dictionary of English)